# how to retrieve data from child in firebase with firesharp and asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase, asp.net-core, fire-sharp

I'm trying to retrieve driver data from firebase's real-time database using firesharp library in order to complete an MVC project using the asp.net core but using this code I can't retrieve all data related to the driver always I'm missing "car details" data, I tried many solutions to retrieve data from this child but none of them works for me.
[this is the data format in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbNKK.png)
[and this is the code I used to retrieve data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj7uJ.png)

Comment: Hi Hamed, welcome to the stack overflow community. This post is unfortunately very low quality at present and is unlike to be able to generate a useful response for you. Please provide some source code of things you have currently tried so members have some building block to work off when giving guidance. Many Thanks, Jaidon

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- Same applies for the database, which you can get as text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).